# How can I use global functions in Angularjs Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I have about 20 spec files and most of them use the same functions repeated in each one. Can I put global functions in the conf.js file that each spec file can use? I read this page `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320400/protractor-angularjs-global-variables`, but it wasn't very helpful and I can't get it working. I tried putting a function in `onPrepare`, but the spec files can't find it. I also tried doing `global.viewByAds = function () {...};`

If anyone can help me I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could simply add a js file and use require

helper.js:

```
module.exports = {
  foo: 'bar',
  doSomething: function () {
    return 1+1;
  }
};
```

in your specs:

```
//require helper.js at specs
var helper = require('./helper.js');
helper.doSomething()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but I can't seem to get it working. I made a file in the same directory called `helper.js` and added the `var helper = require('helper');` line to my spec file, but it says it can't find the helper module. Any ideas?

Comment: @Brendan try require('../helper'); if you dont want it there. depends how you set up your project ...

Comment: I had to use require("../helper.js.coffee") but that could just be a coffeescript thing.