# Protractor expectation that element is eventually present

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

Is there a way to have an expectation that an element is eventually on the page? e.g. a way for

```
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element(by.partialLinkText('Continue'))), 1000, 'Unable to find continue link');
```

to fail with an expectation error instead of a timeout? Essentially a way to have a `isEventuallyPresent()` instead of `isPresent()` in the line below

```
expect(element(by.partialLinkText('Continue')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

For reference, I'm using `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` even though it's an Angular app, and using Jasmine (at least for now).

Comment: Not sure I'm fully understanding but I'll post as a comment for now -- would anything under `Expected Conditions` [link here](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions)  solve your problem?  Specifically `presenceOf` and `visibilityOf` -- I use these to wait for Modals (since they are dynamically appended to HTML only after they are triggered) before beginning test execution.

Comment: Adding to that - you can use `stalenessOf` to make sure an element is **not** present in the DOM, then use the others listed above make sure it is there later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the facts that

- [`browser.wait`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) returns a promise that is resolved once the condition function returns truthy, or rejected if it times out.
- If [`expect`](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd#features) is passed a promise, it only runs the expectation when the promise is resolved

You can make a function that wraps a call to `browser.wait`

```
function eventual(expectedCondition) {
  return browser.wait(expectedCondition, 2000).then(function() {
    return true;
  }, function() {
    return false;
  });
}
```

and then create an expectation

```
expect(eventual(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element(by.partialLinkText('Continue'))))).toBe(true);
```

Or, to make it work on any browser instance, you can monkey-patch the Protractor prototype

```
protractor.Protractor.prototype.eventual = function(expectedCondition) {
  return this.wait(expectedCondition, 2000).then(function() {
    return true;
  }, function() {
    return false;
  });
}
```

and can be used as

```
expect(browser.eventual(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element(by.partialLinkText('Continue'))))).toBe(true);
```

To avoid timeouts, you must make sure that the timeout passed to `browser.wait` is less than the the Jasmine async test timeout, which is specified as [`jasmineNodeOpts: {defaultTimeoutInterval: timeout_in_millis}`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#timeouts-from-jasmine) in the protractor configuration file

Comment: Good idea to wrap it into a reusable function!

Answer (score 2):

The [`presenceOf`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf) *expected condition* used with a `browser.wait()` would allow to have a single line in the test:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.partialLinkText('Continue'))), 1000, 'Unable to find continue link');
```

where `EC` is `protractor.ExpectedConditions` - I usually [make it global](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31208642/771848) in `onPrepare()` through the `global` namespace.

Note that in case of a failure, you would have a *Timeout Error*, but with the `Unable to find continue link` error description.

---

As a side note, it is important to provide a meaningful custom error description, as you've already did. If you want to enforce it, there is a [`eslint-plugin-protractor` plugin](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) to `ESLint` static code analysis tool that [would warn you](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/missing-wait-message.md) if there is a `browser.wait()` used without an explicit error description text.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... However I realise I a) missed "presenceOf" in my original question, and b) Didn't really ask the right question to get an answer I wanted. Not exactly sure if it's the done thing, but I have edited the question.