# Protractor wait for modal-dialog

Tags: javascript, protractor

**How do I get Protractor to wait for a `modal-dialog` pop up?**

Background: After clicking a button protractor should wait for a modal dialog to pop up (and get the time right when the button is clicked and when the dialog pops up). How can I do that? With `browser.wait()`?

The reason is, I have to do End-to-End tests and measure the time the user experiences between clicking the button and getting a feedback from the website.

When I do the test manually, it can take between 5 and 30 seconds for the website to give a feedback. How do I get protractor to wait and then read out the dialog that shows up at the top of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research, I found a very useful script: [waitReady.js](https://gist.github.com/elgalu/2939aad2b2e31418c1bb).
This is my working solution now.
I also added functionality that the script also prints out the text of the modal-dialog.

```
it('Should wait until modal-dialog pops up', function() {
        var dialog = element(by.className('modal-dialog'));
        expect(dialog.waitReady()).toBeTruthy();
        var dialogtext = element(by.className('modal-body-content'));
        expect(dialogtext.waitReady()).toBeTruthy().then(function () {
            dialogtext.getText().then(function (text) {
            console.log('Button Text: ' + text);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

So, you need to measure the time difference between the clicking of button and the time the `modal-dialogue` window comes up.

- Get the Time after button click

  ```
   //you can use any selector for clicking the button
   element(by.buttonText("button_text_for_thebutton").click();


  //getting the time
  var buttonClickTime = new date();
  ```
- Use the `expected conditions` inside of your `browser.wait()` to wait for the `modal-dialog` to pop up

  ```
  //you can use any other locator for modal window
  browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.css('css_locator_formodal'))), 1000, 'Unable to find the modal-popup');

  //get the time post Modal dialog appearance
  var ModalDialogTime = new date();
  ```
- Then get the difference between `buttonClickTime` and `ModalDialogTime` using

  ```
  var timeDifference = ModalDialogTime.getTime() - buttonClickTime.getTime();
  ```

Note : Expected conditions code is taken from [@alexce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) answer in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139499/protractor-expectation-that-element-is-eventually-present).

Comment: I thought about using this solution as well. The problem with this solution is that the time it takes for the modal dialog to pop up can take 5 seconds up to 30 seconds. I don't know how much it'll be, that's why I want to write this test to measure the time and get an average time over several tests.

Comment: Problem is that the `console.log()` already prints out a time of 2 seconds, without waiting for the `browser.wait()`. Also the it prints out, that it's unable to find the `modal-dialog` but it doesn't even wait for the set 30 seconds.