# Protractor: initialise Global variable in one js and use the same var in other js

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I am using protractor to test angularJS apps. I have declared a variable 'logDir' in my test js and want to use it as global variable in other js.

```
//test.js

var regex = /(.*automation)/;
var result = regex.exec(__dirname);
var baseDir = result[0]; 
var libDir = baseDir + '/lib';
```

I want to use libDir variable globally in other js.

I am new to protractor and need help. If more clarification needed, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203398/protractor-set-global-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dump the variable you need globally onto Protractor `browser` object and use it anywhere in the Protractor run Environment

`browser.libDir = baseDir + '/lib'`;

And then if you need it in any other test case you can directly use it as `browser.libDir`

A more professional way to handle this would be declaring global variables in `onPrepare()`.

```
  onPrepare: function() {
       browser.libDir = baseDir + '/lib'
  },
```