# Protractor: use variable from helper file in spec file

Tags: protractor, global-variables, helper

I have perhaps unusual situation where I have to get text out of an element in a helper file and then compare this text in spec file. For example:

Both page files:

```
this.matchText = function(elem) {
    return elem.getText();
};
```

Helper file:

```
        // page objects
        var calculationPage = require('../calculation_page/calculation_page.js');

        // variables
        var globalPrice = "";

        module.exports = exports = function() {
            describe('...
                it('...
                    // initialize page object
                    var calculation = new calculationPage();

                    // store price into global variable
                    calculation.matchText(calculation.price).then(function(text) {
                        globalPrice = text;
                    });

                   // verify price equals expected
                   expect(calculation.matchText(calculation.priceSum)).toContain(globalPrice);

                   ???
                });
            });
        }
```

How to store globalPrice as a variable that could be passed to spec file?

Spec file:

```
// page objects
var homePage = require('../home_page/home_page.js');

// helpers
var getPrice = require('../helpers/get_price.js');

describe('...
    it('...

        // helper - get price
        getPrice();

        // initialize page object
        var home = new homePage();

        // verify if price equals expected
        expect(home.matchText(home.price)).toContain(???);
    });
});
```

How to read global variable from helper file in spec file?

Comment: Why do you have `describe`, `it`, and `expect` blocks in your helper file?

Comment: Because currently I'm calling these as helpers in one spec, but will change them to spec files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump any values you need globally onto Protractor global object - `browser`.

Lets say .. in helper file you need to store the value. Then do this - `browser.globalPrice = text`

And then this value would be available in your spec file. Access it from the `browser` object like any other value `expect(home.matchText(home.price)).toContain(browser.globalPrice);`

Please refer my answer @[Protractor: initialise Global variable in one js and use the same var in other js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996669/protractor-initialise-global-variable-in-one-js-and-use-the-same-var-in-other-j/41997681#41997681)

Comment: THANKS! This is IT! ;) Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just a quick question ;) I can store anything in the way you wrote?

Comment: @jurijk .. Welcome! and yes, you can store anything ... complex objects, references anything