# set global variable in protractor

Tags: protractor, global-variables

I am trying to set global variable for my protractor test. Some thing like

```
window.settest=true
```

What is the best way to do it ?

I am struggling as i am new to protractor. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor set global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203398/protractor-set-global-variables)

Comment: Thank you for your comment!