# Global variables aren't accessible in spec files protractor

Tags: angular, automation, protractor, global-variables, e2e-testing

While automating angular 4 app, i need to declare some global variables i.e. `myVar = 'John'`. I tried declaring it in protractor.conf but its not working. I already have seen [Protractor set global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203398/protractor-set-global-variables) but these solutions don't work for me. Is there any solution to this? I am using protractor version 5.4.2.

```js
exports.config = {
//..
params:{
myVar = 'John'
},

//..
}
```

I already have used this as well but its not working

```js
onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    //this global variable 
    global.myVar = 10000;
    
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

params is an object and therefore requires `:` to assign the value to myVar, not `=`.

```
exports.config = {
  params:{
    myVar:'John'
  },    
}
```

This is called in the following manner

```
console.log(browser.params.myVar)
```

---

The second method should work as it is. You just need to call it

```
onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    //this global variable 
    global.myVar = 10000;

    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
```

Called with

```
console.log(myVar);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. huh... I knew that and making the same mistake again & again.. Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Also notice that when using 'global.blabla' or 'browser.params' with tests parallelization enabled (`shardTestFiles: true`) they will be read-only. This means if you will change these variables in one thread - other threads will be still having old value, since in protractor each test thread runs in separate nodejs process and they do not have shared memory.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing the tutorial:

```
params: {
   myVar: 500;
}

let a = browser.params.myVar;
console.log(a); // 500
```

Comment: sure, https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts