# Have TS accept global variables defined in Protractor config?

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

When adding a global variable in the onPrepare method within the Protractor config, Typescript provides error "Cannot find name '____'" when attempt to utilize in test file.

Below is how I am defining the global variable in my Protractor config.

```
protractorConfig.js

onPrepare: function () {
  global.logger = log4js.getLogger( 'log' );
},
```

Below is how I am utilizing the global variable.

```
homepageTests.js

  it( '1@tests homepage', function () {
       logger.info( 'password for application: ' + pswd );
  } );
```

In reference to the following SO post, setting global variables in the onPrepare method is how Protractor library does this, so it should be valid. 
[Protractor set global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203398/protractor-set-global-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is a TypeScript compilation time error that occurs because TS does not know about `globals` and the fact that something was added there. 
In order to fix that you need to add a declaration for globals somehow or just use assertions.

```
it('1@tests homepage', function () {
   (global as any).logger.info('password for application: ' + pswd);
});
```

Of course `any` can be replace with something more useful.

Another option is to create `globals.d.ts` near to `tsconfig.json` used for e2e tests and put this line there:

```
declare const logger: any; // Again, 'any' may be replaced with real type
```

This way you can access `logger` as you wish

```
it('1@tests homepage', function () {
   logger.info('password for application: ' + pswd);
});
```

You may find some other suitable options [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript)